# Removing specific part of string

Tags: java, regex

I'm parsing every line of a file (XML file) and I need to find `path="this_is_my_path"`. After this, I need to extract whats inside the \". I need to get `this_is_my_path`.

This is what I'm doing:

```
String pattern = ".*path=\"(.*?)\"";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = p.matcher(the_text_file);

while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group().trim());
}
```

After running this, I'm getting this:

```
path="path_to_file"
test="ui_test" path="path_to_other_file"
.....
```

I should be printing this:

```
path_to_file
path_to_other_file
path_to_other_fileX
path_to_other_fileW
```

Comment: Are you reading a XML file?

Comment: Yes. I'm reading an XML file

Comment: Then use a XML parser. Make your life easy.

Comment: Thanks but I can't. I have to do like this.

Comment: No you don't have to do this.

Comment: Any particular reason? Is this a school assignment or something?

Comment: Why? An XML parser is in the standard library, you don't even need to include an external library.

Comment: I'm going to make a t-shirt with "Parsing XML With Regex, Just Say No" on it.

Comment: @Favolas Why don't you quickly erase the XML and make it a plain text file? - But don't forget to add the input for the output you are getting - without any `<` and `>`!

Comment: Ok. Thanks for all the comments. Understand that this is not the way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to use regex, try with this:

```
(?<=path=\")(.*?)(?=\")
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vO8zP3/2)

Or you can use your regex, but without `.*` at the begenning, because it match also any content before `path=` in same line. Then get value by group 1.

Comment: Many thanks for your valuable information. It worked

Answer (score 2):

Why reinvent the wheel? Unless this is a challenge or something?

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

Comment: This should be posted as a comment, not as an answer.

Comment: Or at least the relevant details added to the answer. Links can become stale.

Comment: Sorry will know for future, only new to SO.

Answer (score 2):

One should really try and collect the many reasons why using a regular expression is insufficient for getting anything out *reliably* from an XML file, even if that "anything" is just a measly attribute, e.g. `path` and its (string) value. A simple pattern such as `"path=\"(.*?)\""` is doomed to fail due to the tiniest amount of freedom the XML spec leaves for writing legal XML, and more.

- White space, including line breaks, may occur before and after the equal sign.
- Apostrophes can be used instead of quotes.
- Any character can be written as a numeric or named entity.
- The string could be part of an element or attribute value.
- The string could occur in an XML comment.
- The XML file may be written in an encoding which naive reading as a vanilla text file fails to take into account; hence data may be garbage.

So, just for the record: I strongly suggest to use an XSLT transformation to extract the desired attribute values. This requires just a very simple template. Using an XML parser requires more lines of codes, but it is equally reliable.

And here is the Java code I strongly advocate not to use - it just covers two out of the points mentioned above.

```
String theText = ...;
String pattern = "\\bpath\\s*=\\s*(\"(.*?)\"|'(.*?)')";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = p.matcher(theText);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1).trim());
}
```

(And did you notice the word boundary preceding `path`? Just another chance to go wrong with this approach.)

Comment: Thanks for this useful explanation